# Getting unexpected output when writing a program to find the first perfect square with two odd ending digits

Tags: c++, loops

I'm a beginner taking a C++ class. Thanks for your help. So I have to write a program that finds the first perfect square which ALSO has two odd digits, and it doesn't produce the expected output.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        // 1. Iterate from 1 to 100 and check which number is a perfect square (root is integer)
        int sqrRoot = sqrt(i);
        if (sqrRoot * sqrRoot == i)
        // 2. We need to find the FIRST perfect square who last digit is odd
        {
            int lastDigit = i % 10;
            int secondToLastDigit = i % 100;
     
                if(lastDigit % 2 != 0 && secondToLastDigit % 2 != 0)
                {
                    cout << "Found it. The first perfect square with two odd ending digits is " << i << "\n."; 
                }
            }
        // we printed out every perfect square...
    }
}
```

First, I created a for loop to check from 1 to 1000 to find the first perfect squares in the range. Then in the for loop I tested for it being a perfect square or not in an if statement. Then I created two temporary variables in the `for` loop, `lastDigit` and `secondtoLastDigit` which 'grabs' the last most and second to last most digit using the mod 10 'trick.' Then I check if those two digits are odd or not, and if they are, then print out the perfect square that has ending two odd digits.

Then, when I run it, I noticed I got a bunch of outputs:

```
shahjacob@lenovoLegion7:~/cs211$ ./a.out
Found it. The first perfect square with two odd ending digits is 25
.Found it. The first perfect square with two odd ending digits is 49
.Found it. The first perfect square with two odd ending digits is 81
.Found it. The first perfect square with two odd ending digits is 121
.Found it. The first perfect square with two odd ending digits is 169
.Found it. The first perfect square with two odd ending digits is 225
.Found it. The first perfect square with two odd ending digits is 289
.Found it. The first perfect square with two odd ending digits is 361
.Found it. The first perfect square with two odd ending digits is 441
.Found it. The first perfect square with two odd ending digits is 529
.Found it. The first perfect square with two odd ending digits is 625
.Found it. The first perfect square with two odd ending digits is 729
.Found it. The first perfect square with two odd ending digits is 841
.Found it. The first perfect square with two odd ending digits is 961
```

But I was confused **first**, since some of these outputs are unexpected. First, 121 literally has an even second to last digit. So does `225`. **Second**, why does it not just print the first one?

Please help

Comment: The condition for printing something is `lastDigit % 2 != 0 && secondToLastDigit % 2 != 0` -- what are the values of `lastDigit` and `secondToLastDigit` when your program decides to output `121`? What are those values modulo `2`? *(A focused question about this symptom needs no loop. You can describe your program's goal as background info, but your question can be reduced to setting `i = 121`, then the lines `int lastDigit = i % 10;` `int secondToLastDigit = i % 100;` `if(lastDigit % 2 != 0 && secondToLastDigit % 2 != 0) { cout << "Found " << i << "\n."; }`.)*

Comment: @JaMiT well the `121 % 10` and `121 % 100` would be stored in those two temp variables I created. The results are `1` and `2`. `2 % 2` is obviously 0. So why is it somehow passing as true and printing? Also, what's wrong with my overall logic? My classmates say a perfect square with two odd integers doesn't exist. This code seems to show otherwise? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your second question deserves to be a second question. Similar to what I did for the first question, try to focus your example on this specific symptom. So focus on why the loop does not end. Try to reduce your code to just what is supposed to end the loop.

Comment: *"The results are `1` and `2`."* -- No, they are not. Do not guess what the results are. Go into your program and either use a debugger to look at the variable values or add a diagnostic line to output those values right before the `if` statement.

Comment: @JaMiT I can't because I don't have enough reputation and I'm a new account. Can you help me out and answer a little? So why does the second loop not end, but more importantly, why are these numbers with clearly odd digits that aren't odd passing the test? Also I didn't really even understand your first comment. Please clarify.

Comment: **I can't because I don't have enough reputation and I'm a new account"* -- then I guess you are only allowed to ask one question. Not being able to get what you want because of the rules is not an excuse for breaking them.

Comment: @JaMiT The other person correctly commented that `121 % 100` gives back two digits, not only one. So I changed the variable definition to `secondLastDigit = i % 10 % 10`. Why doesn't it change the output at ALL? The same output was printed.

Comment: @Shah *"The same output was printed."* -- you probably don't have enough output. Add diagnostics (output that will be removed after testing is done). `int lastDigit = i % 10;` **add**  `std::cout << "lastDigit: " << lastDigit << '\n';` `int secondToLastDigit = i % 10 % 10;` **add** `std::cout << "secondToLastDigit: " << secondToLastDigit << '\n';` `if(lastDigit % 2 != 0 && secondToLastDigit % 2 != 0)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int secondToLastDigit = i % 100;` gives **two** last digits. Thus `lastDigit % 2 != 0 && secondToLastDigit % 2 != 0` tests are equivalent tests of the odd number.

Example with 121: `secondToLastDigit` is 1, `secondToLastDigit` is 21. `21 % 2` is `1 % 2` is 1.

You might want `int secondToLastDigit = (i / 10) % 10;`.